# Getting device token in swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

Suddenly, two days ago I stopped receiving push notifications to my iPhone (I send automatic push notifications from my website every 5-10 minutes).

I opened my Xcode project and tried to receive my device token to check if everything works fine, but it is not printing.
It asks me to enable push notifications on my device and when I press "Ok" nothing happens.

The code as the following, in the app delegate :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    registerForPushNotifications(application)
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {
    if notificationSettings.types != .None {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }

    print("Device Token:", tokenString)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to register:", error)
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything like switched on airplane mode or disabled data connectivity and wifi?

Comment: Sometimes question marked as exact duplicate could have a very different cause and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to fix this by logging into my "apple developer" account and agree to the updated terms of service.

Approximately 1 hour after I did this, I started to receive push notifications again.

Thanks for your help guys!